# How to retrieve retrieve Encounters within a given date range using EPIC / FHIR API

Tags: java, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I'm working on a conceptual Java/Spring Boot application, with a developer account on fhir.epic.com.  This app is largely used for statistical analysis and connects using their Backend system configuration.

I have a use case, where on a regular interval (every night),  I wish to make a request to retrieve new encounters.   I can see that the Encounter Search API allows for date ranges, however, there is a requirement on Patient Id.  At this stage, I have no knowledge of the patient, nor interest.

I thought the EpisodeOfCare search API might be an alternative,  but this also requires a patient ID.

I can't see any other available API that would allow me to achieve what I'm attempting,  does anyone know whether this is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Epic, and pretty much every other EHR, does not allow you to query for all newly created encounters regardless of the patient. Some possible alternatives to consider are:

- If you're interested in encounters from a specific set of patients (e.g., all patients with a diagnosis of diabetes), work with the health system to establish a Group and use Bulk FHIR to retrieve their encounters. Note that this won't necessarily tell you which Encounters are new; you would need to determine that from the data or simply overwrite what you already have.
- Leverage Epic Kit, which is available through Vendor Services
- Set up an HL7 interface to receive messages whenever there is a new encounter

Comment: thanks for your rapid response.   There is a distinct group I am interested in,  which would be those patients who've received blood transfusions.  So perhaps Bulk FHIR is the way to go.   I guess that's something new to me I can look into